# Simplify to the nearest $0.1\%$ or nearest $0.1$

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

I met several GRE numeric entry questions which ask to type in my results nearest to $0.1 \%$ or $0.01 \%$ or $0.1 $ or $0.01 $

**Ex.:** After calculations I found that $a=\frac{110}{95}$b and the question is what percent of quantity b, quantity a is greater?

Thus $a=(1.1578..)b$ and I need to write this to the nearest $0.1 \%$. How do I do that and also what is the difference between **nearest to $0.1 \%$** and **nearest to $0.1 $**

Comment: FWIW, 1.1578... is not the answer to the given question...

Comment: @DJohnM I know that. I just need to derive the percent that a is greater than b and write in at the nearest $0.1\%$

Answer (score 1):

When you are asked to *write your result to the nearest $0.1$* you are asked to write a value rounded to the first decimal digit. In your example the result would be $1.2$.

On the other hand, when you are asked to *write your result to the nearest $0.1\%$* you are asked to write a *percentage* value rounded to the first decimal digit (although personally I don't like this formulation). In your example the result would be $115.8\%$.